# Forms (with POST method) not working properly - Google App Engine

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, cookies, wtforms

I deployed my Flask app on Google App Engine (GAE). I've noticed that the forms on my app, like the search bar, login, and signup forms, sometimes work on browsers like Google Chrome, but then they stop functioning after a period, and they might start working again after a while. This behavior persists across different browsers like Firefox and Microsoft Edge.

When I say they're not working, I mean that when I submit a form, the page just refreshes without performing the expected actions. I've checked the logs on Google App Engine and looked for potential errors on Google Dev, but I haven't found any relevant error messages or explanations.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue with a Flask app on Google App Engine? Any insights or solutions would be much appreciated.

* I'm not sure if this behavior is related to headers or not! But if yes, then how can I set that configuration (probably in app.yaml) ?

** Update on the issue with WTForms in Flask and CSRF tokens: Upon further investigation, I've observed that when I submit forms on the deployed version of my application, the CSRF token doesn't appear to be getting stored in the session cookies. Consequently, the line of code form.validate_on_submit() is not functioning as expected. As a consequence, the form validation is failing, leading to the page being rendered again without redirecting.

This is the code for the login part and GAE logs:

```
@App.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """ Handle user login. """
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.authenticate(form.username.data,
                                 form.password.data)
        if user:
            do_login(user)
            welcome_msg = f"Hi {user.username}! Hope you find perfect movies to watch tonight."
            return redirect(url_for("show_homepage", welcome_msg=welcome_msg ))

        flash("Invalid credentials.", 'danger')
   
    print(form.errors)

    return render_template('users/login.html', form=form)
```

```
DEFAULT 2023-08-13T22:43:17.543455Z {'csrf_token': ['The CSRF session token is missing.']}
  {
    "textPayload": "{'csrf_token': ['The CSRF session token is missing.']}",
    "insertId": "64d95c8500084adfaefbed7a",
    "resource": {
      "type": "gae_app",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "moviesbox-391505",
        "version_id": "20230813t223612",
        "zone": "us-west1-4",
        "module_id": "default"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-13T22:43:17.543455Z",
    "labels": {
      "clone_id": "00c61b117cba129e4972a1ec3b0a3b4c2a7df197e75252e9bdb2c9d0b3ff9e4d89229d41aa097a3533c6c6b100ff25101a6265543abecf945c"
    },
    "logName": "projects/moviesbox-391505/logs/stdout",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-13T22:43:17.548982619Z"
  }
```

I tried running the app on different browsers, on my local machine an reading any indication on the logs of GAE.

Update 1: This is how forms are generated and rendered by wtforms and jinja:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, RadioField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, Length


class AddUserForm(FlaskForm):
    """Form for adding users."""

    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[Length(min=6)])
    email = StringField('E-mail', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    image_profile = StringField('(Optional) Image URL')
```

_form.html is the base html for forms:

```
<!-- render a hidden input field with the CSRF token. -->
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
<div class="form-group"></div>

<!-- iterate over the form fields and renders each field that is not a hidden field. -->
        {% for field in form if field.widget.input_type != 'hidden' %}
        
        
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span>
          {% endfor %}
        

        {% if field.widget.input_type == 'radio' %}
          <div class="form-check">
              {{ field(class_="form-check-input") }}
              {{ field.label(class_="form-check-label") }}
          </div>
        {% else %}

        {{ field(placeholder=field.label.text, class="form-control") }}

        {% endif %}
      

        {% endfor %}
```

login.html extends from _form.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body_class %}onboarding{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="login-form">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-5">
      <h1 class="join-message"> Welcome back </h1>

      <form method="POST" id="user_form">
        {% include "_form.html" %}
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-darkgreen">Log in</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

- In **all** cases, the csrf token is generated (but not rendered) and request headers "Cookie" is set to the token.
- In cases I get the **correct** response, response header "Set-Cookie" is set to the correct token as well.
- But, in cases I get the **wrong** response, "Set-Cookie" is empty!

Comment: Research CSRF. The error is `The CSRF session token is missing`. That error appears when the token is missing. The HTML form needs something like `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>`. Your post does not show how you are generating the form HTML.

Comment: I generate forms using classes of WTForms, and then render them in HTML using for loops of Jinja. Everything is working correctly either when I run the code locally, or as I described above it works sometimes on the deployed version. So, my guess is for some reason (probably related to GCP configs) session cookies are blocked to store data.  But I can't find the root!

Comment: I am fairly certain your problem has nothing to do with cookies or App Engine. Show the HTML form you generated. Does it contain a hidden field storing the token? Use the browser debugger to look at the actual downloaded HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback again. I updated my post by adding html of forms and wtform part.

Comment: right after the lins ```<form method="POST" id="user_form">``` in the last code block there is ```{% include "_form.html" %}```. Also, I wrote my code with Python (Flask).